# telerik radgrid issue: when changing pagesize change event

Tags: telerik, radgrid

below is my code for page index change event.

```
protected void Grpgridview_PageIndexChanged(object source,     Telerik.Web.UI.GridPageChangedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {

        Grpgridview.CurrentPageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        LoadGrid();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

my pagesize is 10.

now, whenever i change pagesize from 10 to 20 at runtime the data is not display in grid.

below is my code for pagesize change event.

```
protected void Grpgridview_PageSizeChanged(object source, GridPageSizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Grpgridview.CurrentPageIndex= e.NewPageSize;
    LoadGrid();
}
```

gird is loading from server side but when i change pagesize it will not load data.

Answer (score 0):

You should call **DataBind** in this case.

```
Grpgridview.CurrentPageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
LoadGrid();
```

Of course, it would be better to take advantage of the advanced data-binding offered by Telerik RadGrid.

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-simple-data-binding.html

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-advanced-data-binding.html

Answer (score 0):

```
Protected Sub gridViewMapping_PageSizeChanged(sender As Object, e As GridPageSizeChangedEventArgs)
        gridViewMapping.CurrentPageIndex = e.NewPageSize
        Dim dtRecords = GetGridData()
        gridViewMapping.DataSource = dtRecords
        gridViewMapping.DataBind()
    End Sub
```